# How to stop and force user to enter specific values in bash script?

Tags: bash

I'm trying to force user to enter specific values in bash scripting, but it does not prompt, can someone advice?

```
while IFS= read -r line;
do
until [ "$CONTINUE_EXECUTION" = "Y" -o "$CONTINUE_EXECUTION" = "N" ]; do
  echo "Please press Y to continue or N to exit"
  read CONTINUE_EXECUTION
done
echo $line
done < xx2.txt
```

Comment: Did it not prompt even once? The variable `CONTINUE_EXECUTION` might have got set at the first iteration of loop and might be using the same for further iterations. BTW your script does not do anything different if user enters `Y` or `N`.

Comment: No, it did not.  I have created a shell script file dd1.sh with that code inside for testing. It never prompted and somehow it runs in infinite loop

Comment: You appear to be redirecting from `xx2.txt`.  That redirection will apply to everything inside the `while` loop.  Try removing `<xx2.txt` at the end and see what happens.

Answer (score 3):

The problem in your script is both `read -r line` and `read CONTINUE_EXECUTION` reads from xx2.txt file. The `stdin` is now mapped to `xx2.txt` and both `read` takes input from there.

One way is to use `exec` to create a new fd and use `read -u` to read from that fd.

```
exec 5<xx2.txt
while read -u 5 line   # read from xx2.txt
do
until [ "$CONTINUE_EXECUTION" = "Y" -o "$CONTINUE_EXECUTION" = "N" ]; do
  read -p "Please press Y to continue or N to exit: " CONTINUE_EXECUTION  
       # read from stdin, which is the user's terminal at this point
done
echo $line
CONTINUE_EXECUTION=""
done
```

**PS:** I have removed few parts of your code like `IFS` since i wanted to explain the main part of the required change.

Comment: @cxw: Thanks for the comments.

Comment: No problem :) .  I like your solution with `exec` --- I was messing around with `/dev/console` on Cygwin and not getting anywhere.

Comment: but what is exec 5 ? It has to be 5 all the time ??

Comment: No.. I randomly chose 5 as file descriptor.. Better to choose a fd great than 4 because every process uses 0/1/2 fd.s

Comment: Thanks Fazlin. But I have got an issue with this method. If the file has an entry like this: c:\test\testing1.txt,  new code is removing  \  and returned the line like this: c:testtesting1.txt