# Is it possible to use "read" function with standard input explicitly in shell script under while sentence which is working with file input?

Tags: shell

I am learning shell script. I have a data file. a row represents data of a account.

a data file: data.dat

```
name0 domain0 password0
name1 domain1           # this line is lack of third data.
```

The following script displays all data loading data file by "read" function line by line.

a example script: display_data.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

INPUT_FILE=$1

while read V1 V2 V3
do
  if [ -z "$V3" ]; then
     # when V3 is empty, I want to get it through standard input
     # but it load data from $INPUT_FILE
     read V3  # Here is my problem.
     # read V3 < /dev/stdin  # I want like this.
  fi
  echo "V1 = $V1, V2 = $V2, V3 = $V3"
done < $INPUT_FILE
```

run script by

```
sh display_data.sh data.dat
```

The problem is I could not use read function with standard input inside while sentence because the while sentence uses redirection of data file.
  The third column in data file may lack. I would ask user who runs the script to input the lacked data.

Does anyone have solutions or suggestions?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38077527/how-to-stop-and-force-user-to-enter-specific-values-in-bash-script/38078493#38078493).

You can use `exec` feature to open the input file using different fd and to `read` from stdin.

```
exec {FD}<${INPUT_FILE}
while read -u ${FD} V1 V2 V3
do
 if [ -z "$V3" ]; then
   read V3
 fi  
 echo "V1 = $V1, V2 = $V2, V3 = $V3"
done
```

**PS:** I have modified the script to get unused file descriptor in `$FD` rather than hardcoding the file descriptor.

Comment: Thank you Fazlin. It is a great answer for me. But I have one point anxiety. It specify fd as 5 but could I guarantee I can use fd 5 always?

Comment: Another comment is do you want to delete this question because of duplication. I would like to offer acceptance of the answer to show my thanks but I am afraid that the acceptance is also deleted if I delete this question. Thank you very much.

Comment: I randomly chose 5 as fd.. You can use a bigger number as fd but do not use numbers <4 as fd as they are by default used by every process for stdin/stdout/stderr. This was not exactly a duplicate question but i referred the link because the same `exec` solution could be used to solve both problems.

Comment: I have edited my answer which will prevent you to hardcode `fd`

Comment: Thank you very much Fazlin. It is much better for me. Let me suggest one point to you. It might be better to close file descriptor. From starting your answer I reach a document which closes FD by exec {FD}>&-. I believe this answer has new information, automatic file descriptor assignment. So I don't delete this page. Thank you again.

Comment: Yes closing is better if you are going to re-open the file or re-use the fd. If the script ends after using `FD` then all open files are closed when the process gets killed.